# What are the advanatages of CDFs for RNG over simple random sampling?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random, quantile

If I understand Cumulative Distribution Functions (CDFs) correctly, they can be used for random number generation from a given dataset as follows:

Build a CDF that maps data points to an ordinal probability of any particular data point being <= the given data point. Then use inverse sampling on the CDF by generating a pseudorandom number in the interval of [0, 1), find the probability from the codomain of the CDF that is closest, and then return the data point from the domain that corresponds to that probability.

What are the advantages of this approach over building a list that contains all of the data points, with duplicates, and then generating a random number *r* such that *r* ∈ ℕ  and 1 <= *r* <= *n* (where *n* is the number of data points, including duplicates) and selecting the *r*-th data point from the list?

It seems like both approaches yield the same outcome, unless I am mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create that list in the first place.

When the number of random numbers is large compared to the number of data points, then this might be a cheap price to pay. However when you only - say - need 1000 random numbers out of $10^9$ possible values, then CDF may be your only option.

Another problem concerns rounding errors. With the list method you can only epress rational cumulative distributions and you may need a large denominator to get reasonable accuracy. Even with just two value and probabilitiy densities of $\frac{49}{100}$ and $\frac{51}{100}$ you already need 100 values in your list. But what happens when one is $\frac{1}{\pi}$ and the other  $1-\frac{1}{\pi}$?